# Client-side Google Earth + JS; server-side Java package

Tags: java, kml, google-earth

I'm trying to wrap my head around the proper architecture for a demo app that uses Google Earth. I'd appreciate any suggestions, as I'm new to this!

The web page should:

- display a Google Earth globe
- allow for the user to select certain objects (KML) to be visible interactively (checkboxes, buttons etc)

What I have:

- a Java package already written which produces the KML-data I want to use
- a basic web page which embedds a Google Earth globe.

So, I guess the question is how to get the Java output into Google Earth. As GE's API is for Javascript, is there any way to call the Java-methods from there? Any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options depending on how you want to serve up the kml.

A) You can set up a [network link or use fetchkml](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/kml.html#kmlnetworklink) with url that points to a servlet that gets kml from the java package already written. Check out this [servlet lesson](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava1/servlet.html). Also be sure to set your response contentType to be `"application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"`

B) Store the kml in hidden fields in a form on the web page. Then use javascript to grab the kml from the form DOM and add it using the functions you mentioned.

I would reccomend option A